# discord.js reply with embed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
let prefixList = ['!31 ', '!asdf ', `<@${TAG_ONE}> `, `<@!${TAG_TWO}> `]
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("GUILD_TOKEN");
function hasPrefix(str) {
    for (let pre of prefixList)
        if (str.startsWith(pre))
            return true;
    return false;
}
client.once('message', message => {
    let guild = message.guild;
    if (message.hasPrefix === true) {
        const ServerInfo = newMessageEmbed()
            .setColor('RANDOM')
            .setTitle(`Server infomation on ${guild.name}`)
            .setDescription(`Command executed by ${message.author.tag}`)
            .addFields(
                { name: 'Members', value: `${guild.memberCount}` },
                { name: 'Region', value: `${guild.region}` },
                { name: 'Owner', value: `${guild.owner.tag}`, inline: true },
                { name: 'Created', value: `${guild.createdAt}`, inline: true },
            )
        if (message.content === '$info') message.reply('' + newMessageEmbed);
    }
;
});
client.login('BOT_TOKEN');
```

I'm not getting any errors, but what I want to know is how I can make this reply to the original command with an embed that shows statistics in the guild.

Comment: message objects do not have a `hasPrefix` property. I recommend using `message.content.startsWith(...)`

Comment: Also, your embed object would be `ServerInfo`, `newMessageEmbed` is just invalid. You're getting alot of basic Javascript concepts wrong here. Help yourself by refreshing on JS